# Element not visible when use python and selenium to conduct auto-logging in outlook.com

Tags: python, selenium, outlook

I wanna write a script to automatically log in outlook mail with python and selenium. But after mail address identification, the script always stops at the password part. But these two parts are totally same at all! I must be wrong somewhere. Sincerely ask for help.

My code is like following:

```
browser.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fnlp%3d1%26realm%3dlogin.live.com')

username = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='i0116']")))
username.clear()
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9')
nextButton.click()

password = WebDriverWait(browser, 50).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='i0118']")))
password.clear()
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
signinButton = browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9')
signinButton .click()
```

the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_id('i0118').click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdrive
r\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdrive
r\remote\webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdrive
r\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdrive
r\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visi
ble
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cf
d9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to replace `presence_of_element_located` condition with `visibility_of_element_located`:

```
password = WebDriverWait(browser, 50).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='i0118']")))
password.clear()
```

Comment: Welcome. Please mark this answer as "Accepted" with check mark